# JSF special characters won't save properly

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using `<p:inputTextArea>` to enter XML document content. The problem is that special characters like `<` and `>` are saved in a backing bean like `&lt;` and `&gt;` which is not the way I want. Is there any way to save the entry with `<` and `>` and NOT with `&lt;` and `&gt;`?

Comment: Have you successfully validated that `<` is translated to `&lt;` in the course of JSF to backing bean and not by pasting it into the text field? I have also some `p:inputTextarea` and I can type in `<` which even gets written to the DB without being converted.

Comment: Yes, I have. If I enter < or >, logger displays `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Answer (score -1):

In the backing bean, you should do *unescape* in action method or relevant setter method like this using
`apache common's StringEscapeUtils`

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(enteredText);
//e.g 
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml("&lt; and &gt;"); //will output < and >
```

Comment: Already tried it, no luck. The method just stops when the unescaping should be performed...

Comment: At what point exactly do you try to decode the characters? @peterremec

Comment: When I enter some string in inputTextArea, I would like to press some button to save that entry in a database. There is a method in a request bean, that is executed when the save button is clicked. I'm trying to decode it in that method before storing it in database.